# Powershell - Parse value 00:00:20.12369 to HH:mm:ss

Tags: powershell

How to parse\Convert the value 00:00:20.12369 to 00:00:20 (HH:mm:ss ) Format in powershell ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$time ="00:00:20.12"
Get-Date "$time" -Format "HH:mm:ss"
```

**Output**

```
00:00:20
```

[image]